# Import .tsv while filtering data in r

Tags: r, filter

I have a very large dataset in .tsv format (about 5 gb).
After trying to open the file in R (As it was too large I got problems with R). I thought it might be a good idea filtering data while I import dataset in R in order to remove all the data that I don't need, making easier the task for R. I was wondering if anyone can give me some suggestions in order to do this with R. I found "sqldf package" that seems work with this kind of tasks, but only with .csv file.

I would ask to R to import db.tsv data at the same time filtering "codEx" column to delete all values lower than 0, something like this:

db <- (read.tsv(db.tsv), ....  codEX >0)

Thank you in advance for any help or suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass your own separator in `read.csv.sql` function from `sqldf`. Here is an answer with a small example.

```
#Create a dummy dataset
mt_data <- head(mtcars)
rownames(mt_data) <- NULL
mt_data

#   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#1 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#2 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#3 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#4 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#5 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#6 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1

#Write tsv file
readr::write_tsv(mt_data, 'mydata.tsv')

#Read the data with custom separator filtering the data while reading.
sqldf::read.csv.sql('mydata.tsv', 'select * from file where am = 0', sep = '\t')

#   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#1 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#2 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#3 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

Comment: thank you, it's a good solution